# ResourceBundle - property files inheritance

Tags: java, java-8, sdk, resourcebundle

I am setting up ResourceBundle and I am getting strange results that are against Oracle documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s1804resourcebundleinheritance01.html

I have 3 files:

Animals_fr.properties

```
name=animals_fr
```

Animals_en.propertis

```
name=animals_en
age=5
```

Animals.properties

```
name=animals
age=0
```

Then I have the code:

```
Locale localeFr = new Locale("fr");
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en","US"));
ResourceBundle b = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Animals", localeFr);
System.out.println(b.getString("name"));
System.out.println(b.getString("age"));
```

Based on the Oracle documentation inheritance should be like this:

```
Animals_fr - locale bundle
Animals_en - default locale bundle
Animals - default bundle
```

and the result should be :

```
animals_fr
5
```

But I am getting result:

```
animals_fr
0
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The base bundle for "Animals_fr.properties" is "Animals.properties", not "Animals_en.properties".

Comment: @Progman but shouldn't it go first to the base local bound which is Animals_en as I am setting it in my application?

Comment: Not according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#default_behavior_example, but I can't pinpoint the exact specification where it doesn't load the "_en" file because it sounds like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document, you’ve linked, describes how a resource bundle is looked up, rather than how a single resource key will be resolved.

This matches the [documented default behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#default_behavior), which says

> If the specified locale's language, script, country, and variant are all empty strings, then the base name is the only candidate bundle name. Otherwise, a list of candidate locales is generated from the attribute values of the specified locale (language, script, country and variant) and appended to the base name.

which describes how a single `Locale` leads to a sequence of candidate names. In your case, it would be just `[ Animal_Fr ]`. Then, it says:

> This continues until a result resource bundle is instantiated or the list of candidate bundle names is exhausted. If no matching resource bundle is found, the default control's [`getFallbackLocale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html#getFallbackLocale-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) method is called, which returns the current default locale. A new sequence of candidate locale names is generated using this locale and and searched again, as above.

So, if `Animal_Fr` did not exist, it did fall back to the default locale, trying with a candidate sequence of `[ Animals_en_US, Animals_en ]`.

But since `Animal_Fr` does exist and can be instantiated, this lookup will not continue. Rather, for looking up a particular resource key, the chaining becomes relevant, which is documented as:

> Once a result resource bundle has been found, its *parent chain* is instantiated. If the result bundle already has a parent (perhaps because it was returned from a cache) the chain is complete.
>
> Otherwise, `getBundle` examines the remainder of the candidate locale list that was used during the pass that generated the result resource bundle. […] When it comes to the end of the candidate list, it tries the plain bundle name. With each of the candidate bundle names it attempts to instantiate a resource bundle […].
>
> Whenever it succeeds, it calls the previously instantiated resource bundle's [`setParent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#setParent-java.util.ResourceBundle-) method with the new resource bundle. This continues until the list of names is exhausted or the current bundle already has a non-null parent.

So the linked document is right regarding the overall behavior of `getBundle`, which is the result of the two-step process described in the documentation. But when it comes to the parent chain, which is relevant for the behavior of [`getString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getString-java.lang.String-), only the candidate list of the current lookup phase will be used.

So, depending on which actual bundles do exist, it may end up with either

```
Animals_fr ‣ Animals
```

or

```
Animals_en_US ‣ Animals_en ‣ Animals
```

in your example setup.